# Pinta can not open file - permission denied

Tags: 18.04, permissions, directory, drive, pinta

My ubuntu 18.04 is installed in the SSD.I installed [pinta](https://www.pinta-project.com/) from ubuntu software but can not open files from my hard disk, says permission denied.
But can open files from SSD where ubuntu is installed(Document, Download... folders). How do i give permission to all the drives. Facing same problem with some other apps too.

[image]

Files from `Computer` is accessible to pinta.

[image]

Here is the `findmnt | grep /media` command output

[image]

When I click `Details` I get the following information:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/media/asif/New Volume/Desktop/o1.jpg" is denied.
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0019e] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean isAsync, System.Boolean anonymous) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access) [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess)
  at Pinta.Core.GdkPixbufFormat.Import (System.String fileName, Gtk.Window parent) [0x00001] in :0 
  at Pinta.Core.WorkspaceManager.OpenFile (System.String file, Gtk.Window parent) [0x0003d] in :0
```

Output of `snap list pinta`

```
error: no matching snaps installed
```

Output for command `apt policy pinta`

```
pinta:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.6-2
  Version table:
     1.6-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
asif@asif-HP:~$
```

Here is output for `flatpak list` and `dpkg -l pinta`
[image]

Some of the output for `sudo locate -i pinta`:

```
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_dash.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_dash_disabled.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_dash_prelight.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_dash_pressed.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_focused.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_focused_prelight.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_focused_pressed.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_unfocused.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_unfocused_prelight.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity/unmaximize_unfocused_pressed.svg
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/thumbnailers/librsvg.thumbnailer
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/upstart/sessions
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/upstart/sessions/unity-gtk-module.conf
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/xml/fontconfig
/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8/usr/share/xml/fontconfig/fonts.dtd
/var/cache/apparmor/snap-update-ns.pinta-james-carroll
/var/cache/apparmor/snap.pinta-james-carroll.pinta
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.pinta-james-carroll
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.pinta-james-carroll.pinta
/var/lib/snapd/cookie/snap.pinta-james-carroll
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pinta-james-carroll_pinta.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/inhibit/pinta-james-carroll.lock
/var/lib/snapd/mount/snap.pinta-james-carroll.fstab
/var/lib/snapd/mount/snap.pinta-james-carroll.user-fstab
/var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf/snap.pinta-james-carroll.pinta.bin
/var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf/snap.pinta-james-carroll.pinta.src
/var/lib/snapd/sequence/pinta-james-carroll.json
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pinta-james-carroll_6.snap
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pinta-james-carroll_8.snap
/var/lib/ureadahead/snap.pinta-james-carroll.8.pack
/var/snap/pinta-james-carroll
/var/snap/pinta-james-carroll/6
/var/snap/pinta-james-carroll/8
/var/snap/pinta-james-carroll/common
/var/snap/pinta-james-carroll/current
```

Comment: Have you installed *pinta* from snap? What does `snap list pinta` output?

Comment: @Raffa No, output is `error: no matching snaps installed`

Comment: @mook765 please check here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9brf8Kpgd7/

Comment: Please help us understand. Are you using pinta for windows in *wine*? How do you run pinta? How did you try to open that picture? What does `apt policy pinta` return? How did you install pinta? What version of Ubuntu is installed? Please [edit] to add the information.

Comment: @Raffa  Please check my updated question

Comment: Please add the output of `flatpak list` and `dpkg -l pinta`. I am still trying to find where you installed pinta from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Info

You have snap **`pinta-james-carroll`** installed.

Please read [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/confusion-of-snaps-in-ubuntu-software/20170) and [this](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/pinta-snap-not-visible-in-ubuntu-software/22880)

#### Solution

**Either**, remove `pinta-james-carroll` like so:

```
sudo snap remove pinta-james-carroll
```

**Then**, install `pinta` from snap like so:

```
sudo snap install pinta
```

**Then**, set permissions in **Ubuntu Software** like so:

[image]

**Or even better**, remove snap `pinta-james-carroll` like so:

```
sudo snap remove pinta-james-carroll
```

and if you have installed snap `pinta`, remove it as well like so:

```
sudo snap remove pinta
```

**Then**, install pinta from the official repositories with APT like so:

```
sudo apt install pinta
```

Comment: Pinta doesn't appear on command `flatpak list`, i have updated my question

Comment: @mahfujasif It is getting a little bit odd!. We are still hunting for **pinta**.Please run `sudo updatedb` then run `sudo locate -i pinta` and add the output to your question.

Comment: output is too long, about 70k lines, so i have uploaded the text file here, please download https://file.io/IgcH2QQA9bsl

Comment: @mahfujasif Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Type the following command in a terminal:

```
snap connect pinta:removable-media
```

It should then be able to access those drives.

Comment: Not working, probably because i didn't installed from snap

Answer (score 2):

If you install Pinta from the "Software" GUI, then you get a "snap" version that runs in some kind of sandbox so it cannot open files in your `/tmp` folder for example.

The solution is to remove the snap version and install it by running this command on your terminal:

```
sudo apt install pinta
```

as described above. Then you get a normal application.