# VLC Won't Open Files from NFS Share

Tags: vlc, nfs

I have an mkv file on a Synology DS220j mounted via NFS. If I right click the file and open with VLC it throws an error:

`VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///nas`

I have to copy it locally to the internal disk `/dev/sdc1` and then open it there for it to play. Why does this happen? Any ideas?

Comment: If you installed VLC from snap, then it could be permissions issue. See [this similar post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321337/pinta-can-not-open-file-permission-denied) about pinta installed from snap.

Comment: Open Tools -> Messages, set Verbosity to 2 before playback, and it will show more detailed errors.

Comment: Would that ne the same if you mounted your Synology NAS with SMB? An alternative is to convert the file using `handbrake` from the Ubuntu Software Center. See [this reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/361973/how-to-convert-mkv-videos-to-mp4/)

Comment: @24601 seems to happen with any kind of network share.

Comment: @Raffa nope not snap just the 20.04 app center.

Comment: @Rinzwind will try that.

Comment: App center installs snap applications as well... to know for sure, run `snap list` and see if VLC is listed there.